# Matplotlib setting the x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to visualize the raster data consisting of 40 bands with matplotlib by taking the reflection values ​​with the shapefile points that I created.

[image]

For example, in the code I wrote below, the band_n variable takes the average of Band 33,36,39,40 and plots it with the B2 title. In this respect, I am expecting 4 ticks on the x-axis of each plot.

```
    prof = train_pts.groupby (['classes']).mean ()
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (17,20))
band_n = [ 'Band [33,36,39,40]', 'Band [2,6,11,16]', 'Band [3,7,12,17]', 'Band [4,8,13,30]', 'Band [20,22,14,26]', 'Band [2,26,11,30]','Band [2,26,11,30]']
band_name = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'NDVI', 'VV', 'VH']
n = 1
for i, ba in enumerate(band_n):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(4,2,i + 1)
    ax.title.set_text(band_name[i])
    band_val = prof[prof.columns[prof.columns.to_series().str.contains(ba)]]
    for index, row in band_val.iterrows():
        color = cmap (index)
        ax.plot (row,color=color)
    ax.set_xticklabels([(str (band_n) for band_n in range(1, len(row)+1))]) #replace the column names with numbers
    ax.legend(loc='best', fontsize='small', ncol=1, labels=class_names)
n=n+1
```

But when I run this I get warnings with this plots : [image]

Isn't this code suitable for converting the band_n variable to string and printing it on the x axis? Or is there an easier way?

```
ax.set_xticklabels([(str (band_n) for band_n in range(1, len(row)+1))]) #replace the column names with numbers
```

Comment: `[(str (band_n) for band_n in range(1, len(row)+1))]` appears to be a list with 1 element, the generator expression. Try removing the parentheses: `[str (band_n) for band_n in range(1, len(row)+1)]`

Comment: hm, I tried but now it says invalid syntax error.

Comment: What's the error message? My snipped worked for me with `row=[1,2,3]`.

Comment: Input In [73]
    ax.set_xticklabels [str (band_n) for band_n in range(1, len(row)+1)]
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: No no, not remove all parentheses. Just the ones inside your list comprehension. Like this: `ax.set_xticklabels([str (band_n) for band_n in range(1, len(row)+1)])`

Comment: Now it's working but for example first plot the x-axis max value is 15, the second one's is 23, and the others change... I want to set all of them in same range (1, 4).

Comment: If you want the numerical limits from (1,4), then use `ax.set_xlim(1, 4)`. If you want the labels to be in the range (1,4) with the same tick numerical positions, then you'll need to attribute 1 tick label to each tick. If you want them equally spaced, `ax.set_xticklabels(np.linspace(1, 4, num=len(ax.get_xticks()))`.